# Can commands be intercepted based on their type?

Tags: permissions, authorization, interceptor, axon

In [Axon](https://axoniq.io), [Command Interceptors](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/1.3-infrastructure-components/command-dispatching#command-interceptors) seem to intercept any and every command. For permission checking, I need to base my decision on the type of command to see whether it is allowed in the current context.

```
@Override
public BiFunction<Integer, CommandMessage<?>, CommandMessage<?>> handle(List<? extends CommandMessage<?>> messages) {
    return (index, command) -> {
        // Check permissions
        return command;
    };
}
```

Usually I would prefer to register an interceptor per command type and handle the permission checks in dedicated objects. How would I do it with Axon? Will I need to have a load of `instanceof` if-statements in a single interceptor? Does anyone have a good example of permission checking with Axon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point (Axon 4.0) the framework does not allow you the option to register `DispatchInterceptors` per command payload type directly. So what you're suggesting to do, the if-blocks/switch-statements, is the best thing you could do at this point.

Although I am not certain how fine grained your permission checks are, what you could do is have some form of permission annotation on the commands, with a specific value/enum you need to set on it. That way you do not have to tie in your payload type into the dispatcher directly, but could just check if the annotation exists and if so, check it's value for the kind of permission check which should be performed on it.

That would very likely result in a far smaller if-block/switch-statement than checking per  payload type.